# Saving a image with blob type on mysql using django and ReactJS

Tags: python, reactjs, django, blob, mysql-python

I would like to save a blob in mysql using django , but I have the following problem sometimes the image is saved as none and sometimes it gives a bad request problem, how can I solve this?
Here my view.py:

```
class RegiaoAPIView(APIView):
    serializer_class = RegiaoSerializer

    def get(self, request, pk=None, format=None):
        try:
            if pk is None:
                regioes = Regiao.objects.all()
                serializer = self.serializer_class(regioes, many=True)
                return Response(serializer.data)
            else:
                regiao = Regiao.objects.get(pk=pk)
                childs = Regiao.objects.filter(id_regiao_superior=regiao)
                serializer = self.serializer_class(regiao)
                serializer_apontando = self.serializer_class(childs, many=True)

                response_data = {
                    "regiao": serializer.data,
                    "childs": serializer_apontando.data if pk else None
                }

                return Response(response_data)
        except Regiao.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({"detail": "No Regioes found"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({"detail": str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

    def post(self, request):
        try:
            # print("Dados binários da imagem:", request.data.get('imagem'))
            print("Entrou na view de criação")
            imagem_base64 = request.data.get('imagem', None)
            new_data = request.data.copy()

            if imagem_base64:
                print("Entrou no tratamento de imagem")
                imagem_bytes = base64.b64decode(imagem_base64)
                new_data['imagem'] = imagem_bytes

            poligono_valor = request.data.get('poligono', None)
            extend_valor = request.data.get('extend', None)

            poligono_resultante = createPolygon(poligono_valor)
            if extend_valor is not None:
                new_data['extend'] = json.dumps(extend_valor)
            new_data['poligono'] = poligono_resultante

            print("Dados antes da serialização:", new_data)

            serializer = self.serializer_class(data=new_data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                print("Dados válidos, criando objeto...")
                serializer.save()
                print("Objeto criado com sucesso")
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            else:
                print("Erros de validação:", serializer.errors)
                return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        except Exception as e:
            print("Erro no servidor:", str(e))
            return Response({"detail": str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

Here my model.py:

```
class Regiao(models.Model):
    class TipoEscolha(models.TextChoices):
        EXTERNO = "EXTERNO",'Externo'
        INTERNO = "INTERNO",'Interno'

    nome = models.TextField()
    sigla = models.TextField()
    descricao = models.TextField()
    extend = models.JSONField(blank=True, null=True) # Armazenar como array de floats
    tipo = models.CharField(
        max_length=7,
        choices=TipoEscolha.choices,
        default=TipoEscolha.EXTERNO
    ) # externo, interno
    imagem = models.BinaryField(blank=True,null = True)
    poligono = models.JSONField(blank=True,null = True)
    id_regiao_superior = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    class Meta: # DEFINE O NOME PERSONALIZADO DA TABELA
        db_table = 'regiao'

    def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.nome }'
```

Here my serializer:

```
class RegiaoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Regiao
        fields = ('id', 'nome', 'sigla', 'descricao', 'extend', 'tipo', 'imagem', 'poligono', 'id_regiao_superior')

    def get_imagem(self, obj):
        return base64.b64encode(obj.imagem).decode('utf-8') if obj.imagem else None

    def create(self, validated_data):
        imagem_base64 = validated_data.pop('imagem', None)
        instance = super().create(validated_data)
        print(imagem_base64)
        if imagem_base64:
            instance.imagem = base64.b64decode(imagem_base64)
            instance.save()
            
        return instance
```

Here is my front-end component:

```
export default function AdicionarRegiao() {

    const [regioes, setRegiao] = useState([]);
    const renderedRegioes = regioes.map((region, index) => (
        <Box key={index}>
            {Object.keys(region).map((key) => (
                <Typography key={key}>
                    {key}: {region[key]}
                </Typography>
            ))}
        </Box>
    ));

    const [newRegiao, setNewRegiao] = useState({
        nome: "",
        sigla: "",
        descricao: "",
        tipo: "",
        poligono: "",
        extend:[],
        id_regiao_superior: "",
        imagem:""
    });

    const handleInputChange = (event) => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        if (name === "extend") {
            setNewRegiao((prevRegiao) => ({
                ...prevRegiao,
                extend: value.split(',').map(item => item.trim())  
            }));
        } else {
            setNewRegiao((prevRegiao) => ({
                ...prevRegiao,
                [name]: value
            }));
        }
    };

    const handleImageChange = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];

    if (file) {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (e) => {
            const base64String = btoa(
                new Uint8Array(e.target.result)
                    .reduce((data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte), '')
            );

            setNewRegiao((prevRegiao) => ({
                ...prevRegiao,
                imagem: base64String,  // Set the base64-encoded image data
            }));
        };

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
};  

const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
        const response = await addRegiao({
            ...newRegiao,
            tipo: newRegiao.tipo || 'EXTERNO',
        });
 
        if (response.status === 201) {
            // Success: handle the response data as needed
            console.log('Response data:', response.data);

            // Add the newly created region to the list if needed
            setRegiao((regioes) => [response.data, ...regioes]);
        } else {
            // Handle errors appropriately
            console.error('Error:', response.statusText);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('API request error:', error);
    }

    // Reset the form fields
    setNewRegiao({
        nome: "",
        sigla: "",
        descricao: "",
        tipo: "",
        poligono: "",
        id_regiao_superior: "",
        extend: [],
        imagem: "", // Reset the image field to an empty string
    });
};

    const [allRegioesNameId, setAllRegioesNameId] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchRegioes = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await getAllRegiao();

                const regioesObj = {};
                response.data.regiao.forEach(regiao => {
                    regioesObj[regiao.nome] = regiao.id;
                });

                setAllRegioesNameId(regioesObj); // Atualize o estado com o objeto
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Erro ao buscar regiões:', error);
            }
        };

        fetchRegioes();
    }, []);

    function optionsLabel() {
        const options = [];
        for (const [nome, id] of Object.entries(allRegioesNameId)) {
            options.push(<option key={nome} value={id}>{nome}</option>)
        }
        return options
    }   

    


    return (
        <>
            <Stack
                    display ='flex'
                    justifyContent= 'center'
                    alignItems= 'center'
                    gap={2}
            >
                    <TextField
                        label='Nome'
                        type='text'
                        name='nome'
                        value={newRegiao.nome}
                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                    />
                    <TextField
                        label='Sigla'
                        type='text'
                        name='sigla'
                        value={newRegiao.sigla}
                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                    />
                    <TextField
                        label='Descrição'
                        type='text'
                        name='descricao'
                        value={newRegiao.descricao}
                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                    />
                    <TextField
                        label='Extend'
                        type='text'
                        name='extend'
                        value={newRegiao.extend}
                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                    />
                    <label>
                        tipo:
                        <select
                            type="text"
                            name="tipo"
                            value={newRegiao.tipo}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                        >
                            <option></option>
                            <option>EXTERNO</option>
                            <option>INTERNO</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>

                    <TextField
                        label='Poligono'
                        type='text'
                        name='poligono'
                        value={newRegiao.poligono}
                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                    />
                    
                    <input
                        type="file"
                        accept="image/*"
                        onChange={(event) => handleImageChange(event)}
                    />

                    <label>
                        ID_regiao_superior:
                        <select
                            name="id_regiao_superior"
                            value={newRegiao.id_regiao_superior}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                        >   
                            <option> </option>
                            {optionsLabel()}
                        </select>
                    </label>

                    <Button variant="contained" type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>Adicionar Região</Button>
            </Stack>
            <Box sx={{
                display: 'flex',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center'
            }}>
                {renderedRegioes}
            </Box>
        </>
    );
}
```

I want to save the image as a blob(binary) on the fild "imagem" on mysql